# Reducing the “Time for the first byte” on my website

Tags: wordpress, performance, apache, dns

My website is: [ApostaFeita](http://www.apostafeita.com/)

The website is in Wordpress and if you go to the homepage, you'll see that before the page loads, the browser waits ...

How could I reduce Time for the first byte?

[image]

Comment: Time to first byte makes it sound like you trying to optimize TCP/IP - you really want to find which Wordpress module is taking forever and remove or optimize it

Comment: I've already de-activated all plugins, and still continues to be slow

Comment: What hosting settings you're using for the site? Shared, Dedicated, VPS ... Your server is based on Apache, Nginx? you need to give more information to help you ...